# Rails 4 scope has_and_belongs_to_many qualified by the through table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have a locations and users table, with a joining table locations_users.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

thins like `location.users` work correctly now.  What I would like to achieve is something like: `location.members`

In straight SQL, this gets what I'm looking for:

```
select * from locations l left outer join locations_users lu on lu.location_id=l.id left outer join users u on lu.user_id=u.id where l.location_id=1 and lu.member=true;
```

Comment: Try with this `Location.includes(:locations_users, :users).where(locations_users.location_id => location.id,locations_users.user_id => user.id,locations_users.member => 'true')` didn't tested.

Comment: Have you tried to add HABTM with condition like this:
`has_and_belongs_to_many :members, class_name: "User", join_table: "locations_users", -> { where('users.member = ?', true) }`

Comment: @VinhBS should work, but note, condition needs to come first -- `has_and_belongs_to_many :members, -> { ... }, ...`

Comment: Your question implies (`lu.member = true`) you have `member` column on your `locations_users` table. You should use a `has_many through` relationship instead. HABTM join tables only contain references.

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many :members, -> {where('locations_users.member = ?', true)}, class_name: "User", join_table: "locations_users"` is working.

Comment: and you'll have to use raw sql to update the `locations_users.member` column because you don't have a join model (such as LocationUser) with a `member` attribute. It might be sufficient at the moment, but you might have to convert to `has_many through` later as your application grows.

Comment: Thanks @DamienRoche, I've got two branches trying each way.